# Javac and Primitives: Boxed vs. Unboxed

Tags: java, javac, primitive, boxing

My question is: why do primitive types have to be wrapped in an object, when it is also a possibility to have the compiler set things right for you?

1. calls to a primitive value x's methods can be translated from x.call() to X.call(x) - this is what I try to illustrate below.
2. generics aren't kept around at runtime (right?), so it isn't the case that you need to access class information at runtime - you could simply replace every instance of Integer by int and rewrite method calls as above, and end up with executable code.

So basically, what I'm asking is: what am I missing here?

---

I've been wondering about this for some time: Why can't the Java compiler translate...

```
int a = 482;
int b = 12;
System.out.println((a + b).toHexString());
```

...to the following code...

```
int a = 482;
int b = 12;
System.out.prinln(Ints.toHexString(a + b));
```

...and thus remove the entire need for boxing and unboxing?

(Thus, compile method calls to (static) function calls, and keep a single instance of Int.class around in case it's needed - e.g. after a call of Ints.getClass(_)?)

---

Comment added for clarity:

> @Adam: No, I do not think it causes
>   boxing/unboxing. The example attempts
>   to illustrate how primitives could be
>   treated as objects in the language,
>   but as primitives by the compiler.
>   This would remove the (slight)
>   overhead in runtime, and a confusing
>   thing in the language. Therefore the
>   intended question was exactly: why
>   didn't the extremely talented compiler
>   developers pick this solution? Because if they didn't, there
>   must be a clear impossibility that I'm
>   not seeing. And I'd like to know what
>   it is. – Pepijn

Comment: Instead of `Ints`, I presume you meant `Integer`, correct? This will definitely confuse people.

Comment: What's the purpose of your question/suggestion?  Do you believe that auto(un)boxing is slow, and this alternative would be faster?  If so, since you're talking about alternative bytecode representations (whereby the compiler has a lot of freedom), why do you think this idea has not been chosen by the extremely talented compiler developers?

Comment: It is hard to understand your sample code. Do you think that the first sample is causing boxing/unboxing? It shouldn't, because `a` and `b` are primitives. I ask this because `toHexString()` can only be called on an `Integer`, not an `int`. Did you mean to define `a` and `b` of type `Integer` instead of type `int`?

Comment: @Adam: No, I mean `Ints`. I wanted to emphasize that I was talking of a fictional implementation. And if anything is confusing, it's the change from `int` to `Integer`, instead of `Int`. (The plural `Ints` came from too much time spent with Google Guave.)

Comment: @Andrej: The purpose was learning why there is such a sharp distinction between primitives and objects (and thus two types for `int`) in the language, while I believe this is in no way necessary (which is what my example attempts to illustrate).

Comment: @Adam: No, I do not think it causes boxing/unboxing. The example attempts to illustrate how primitives could be treated as objects in the language, but as primitives by the compiler. This would remove the (slight) overhead in runtime, and a confusing thing in the language. Therefore the intended question was exactly: why didn't the extremely talented compiler developers pick this solution? Because if they didn't, there must be a clear impossibility that I'm not seeing. And I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: Boxing/Unboxing is not the same thing as Generics. Generics information is removed after compilation, but not boxing/unboxing information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you meant `Integer.toHexString`, not `Ints.toHexString`. The latter is not part of `java.lang` and the compiler would have no way to know anything about it.

In theory, the compiler could translate calls of `(a + b).toHexString()` to `Integer.toHexString(a + b)`, if the Java language specifies such a translation. (For example, auto-boxing of an `int a` to an `Integer` is specified to be `Integer.valueOf(a)`.)

I guess the Java language maintainers decided that that is too "magical" for Java programmers---in all versions of Java, primitive types do not have methods or fields. Java, in general, is designed to avoid syntactic sugar---that is why it's generally more verbose than most other languages.

Comment: What would be "magical" about it? It's not syntactic sugar but a simple compiler optimization that would be completely transparent to the programmer. OTOH what *is* autoboxing and -unboxing if not syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Michael: Just updated with explanation---historically primitive types never had methods or fields (this ain't Ruby ;-)). Adding that for primitive types would be too magical for people who think of primitives as "non-objects".

Comment: Autoboxing etc. are indeed syntactic sugar, and I'm not saying that Java avoids all instances of it, just that it has a policy of avoiding it except in cases where not having it would impact a lot of programmers in a bad way. As far as I understand, Java 5 introduced autoboxing/autounboxing because its newly-introduced generics supported boxed types only---and were the autoboxing/unboxing to be absent, generics' non-support for primitive types would have been much more painfully felt.

Comment: For example, suppose you had `List<Integer> nums`. Without autounboxing, you could not use this: `for (int num : nums)`. Since you can't have `List<int>`, you would be forced to write `for (Integer num : nums)` if there were no autounboxing.

Comment: @Chris: So what you are saying here is that the Integer type (and friends) arose from limitation in the implementation of Generics?

Comment: @Pepijn: No, the Integer wrapper type and friends (and boxing, though not auto-boxing) are much older than generics, they were already in the first version of the language.

Comment: @Pepijn: Nope; what I was saying was that without autoboxing and autounboxing, generics in Java would be somewhat less usable. I wrote that to explain to @Michael that, while Java's language designers are resistant to syntactic sugar, they will still support it when it has great value.

Answer (score 1):

So, we could map methods called on primitive types to static methods of their wrapper types, fine.

This does not relate to boxing/unboxing at all, it is only syntactic sugar to write the same method call in another way - and only a quite small number of methods, these predefined in the wrapper classes.

**Boxing** is necessary when you want to treat a primitive value as an object, for example:

- pass it to a method which only accepts objects
- put it in a variable of object type
- return it from a method which has to return objects

Special (but quite important) cases of these are:

- put it into an object array
- put it into a collection

**Unboxing** is necessary if we got such a boxed primitive and want to have the pure form of it, for example after calling a method which returns objects, or taking the value from a variable.

Before Java 5 (or 1.5), we had to do all this boxing and unboxing manually, by the `.valueOf()` method or `toXXX()`. Now it is done automatically whenever necessary (autoboxing).

Answer (score 0):

What would the compiler do for

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(5);
int i = list.get(0);
```

You need an instance of Integer here, hence the need for boxing/unboxing.